# date availability checker working only once

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, ms-access

The problem I have here is, that the code actually works, but it works only once. 
For example if I have selected a date and time thats already in the database it shows date unavailable as its supposed to and if I select a date thats not in db it shows date available. No problem until then, but after these both labels have been shown once and if i select an unavailable date the third time, the code doesnt execute again. I mean, it just stays at the previous shown label. How can I make a loop on this?

The front end code is as below:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptmanager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        Sys.Application.add_load(jScript);
    </script>
    <div id="dvRecWed" style="display: none">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="PnlUsrDetails" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtReceptionDate" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" CssClass="datepicker" placeholder="mm/dd/yy" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="reset_ddl" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:DropDownList AutoPostBack="true" ID="ddlReceptionTime" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="txtUsername_TextChanged">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="-1">--Select--</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Forenoon">Forenoon</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Afternoon">Afternoon</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="FullDay">Full Day</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <div id="checkdate" class="checkdate" runat="server" visible="false">
                    <asp:Image ID="imgstatus" runat="server" Width="17px" Height="17px" />
                    <asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
</form>
```

And the back end code is as below

```
protected void txtUsername_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ddlReceptionTime.Text))
    {
        string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MandapamDatabase"].ConnectionString;
        OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connString);
        // SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from UserInformation where UserName=@Name", con);
        string selectQuery = "SELECT FunctionTime FROM function WHERE FunctionDate=@FunctionDate AND FunctionTime='FullDay'";
        connection.Open();
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(selectQuery, connection);
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandText = selectQuery;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FunctionDate", txtReceptionDate.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FunctionTime", ddlReceptionTime.Text);
        OleDbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            checkdate.Visible = true;
            imgstatus.ImageUrl = "~/img/cross.png";
            lblStatus.Text = "Date Unavailable";
            lblStatus.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }
        else
        {
            checkdate.Visible = true;
            imgstatus.ImageUrl = "~/img/check.png";
            lblStatus.Text = "Date available";
        }
    }

    else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ddlReceptionTime.Text))
    {
        string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MandapamDatabase"].ConnectionString;
        OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connString);
        // SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from UserInformation where UserName=@Name", con);
        string selectQuery = "SELECT FunctionTime FROM function WHERE FunctionDate=@FunctionDate AND FunctionTime=@FunctionTime";
        connection.Open();
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(selectQuery, connection);
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandText = selectQuery;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FunctionDate", txtReceptionDate.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FunctionTime", ddlReceptionTime.Text);
        OleDbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            checkdate.Visible = true;
            imgstatus.ImageUrl = "~/img/cross.png";
            lblStatus.Text = "Date Unavailable";
            lblStatus.ForeColor= System.Drawing.Color.Red;

        }
        else
        {
            checkdate.Visible = true;
            imgstatus.ImageUrl = "~/img/check.png";
            lblStatus.Text = "Date Available";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        checkdate.Visible = false;
    }
}



protected void reset_ddl(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ddlReceptionTime.SelectedValue = "-1";
}
```

Comment: Dots aren't herd-animals. You can set them wherever appropriate. not only in groups of 3.

Comment: I think something is wrong in your post, why have 2 times the same block of code ?

Comment: No, the difference is the second query parameter. He could put an if block there, but he choose to repeat the whole shebang.

Comment: how do i do the if block? I'm new to this. so i dont know a lot about this. so i did what i can with the little knowledge i have. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your expected behavior?

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtReceptionDate" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" CssClass="datepicker" placeholder="mm/dd/yy" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="reset_ddl" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:DropDownList AutoPostBack="true" ID="ddlReceptionTime" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="txtUsername_TextChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Value="-1">--Select--</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Forenoon">Forenoon</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Afternoon">Afternoon</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="FullDay">Full Day</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Based on your code you are calling the `txtUsername_TextChanged` during the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event of the drop down list.

This means even if you change the date value of your date picker, the event won't fire. Instead, `reset_ddl` will trigger during the `OnTextChanged` event.

We don't know what does `reset_dll` do. If you want the code that checks the availability of the date to trigger then place that on the `OnTextChanged` event of the date picker textbox and not on the drop down list.

Comment: reset_dll resets the value loaded in the dropdownlist to the very first one                                                                                                                protected void reset_ddl(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ddlReceptionTime.SelectedValue = "-1";
    }

Comment: and your answer helped too as youve said the reset_dll triggers onTextChanged event as soon as i change the date before i could select the time which messed up with the code and i removed it and cleared both the textbox and ddl as soon as i get the date unavailable thanks for your help sincerely

Answer (score 0):

i found the where the problem lies actually there isnt a problem with the code its working perfectly the problem was in my db